# Exception in thread "main" org.spring....beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'FirstStep': Instantiation of bean failed

Tags: spring-batch

am trying to run my application am getting error.I am using spring batch patitioning to run multiple threads of job.Here am getting exception is step name is Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean class specified on bean definition.**please suggest me any one.**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Step': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean class specified on bean definition
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1016)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:660)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at john.deere.com.PartApp.runTest(PartApp.java:18)
    at john.deere.com.PartApp.main(PartApp.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean class specified on bean definition
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:354)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:66)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    ... 14 more
```

in my configuration file is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

            <context:component-scan base-package="john.deere.com" />
            <import resource="applicationContext.xml"/>
            <import resource="ApplicationDB.xml"/>

       <job id="partitionJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">

        <!-- master step, 10 threads (grid-size)  -->
        <step id="Step">
        <partition step="slave" partitioner="rangePart">
            <handler grid-size="10" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
        </partition>
        </step>

<step id="slave" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="itemReader" processor="itemProcessor" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="1" />
            </tasklet>
        </step> 
      </job>



        <bean id="rangePart" class="john.deere.com.PartitionerEx" />

        <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />

        <bean id="itemProcessor" class="john.deere.com.EmpProcessor"
            scope="step">
            <property name="threadName" value="#{stepExecutionContext[name]}" />
        </bean>

        <!-- csv file writer -->
        <bean id="itemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter"
            scope="step" >
            <property name="resource"
                value="file:csv/outputs/employee.processed#{stepExecutionContext[fromId]}-#{stepExecutionContext[toId]}.csv" />
            <!-- <property name="appendAllowed" value="false" /> -->
            <property name="lineAggregator">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
                    <property name="delimiter" value="," />
                    <property name="fieldExtractor">
                        <bean
                            class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                            <property name="names" value="id, name, age, salarey, address" />
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="itemReader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader"
        scope="step">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="queryProvider">
          <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="selectClause" value="select id, name, age, salary, address" />
            <property name="fromClause" value="from employee" />
            <property name="whereClause">
             <value>
             <![CDATA[
             where id >= :fromId and id <= :toId
             ]]>
             </value>
             </property>
            <property name="sortKey" value="id" />
          </bean>
        </property>
        <!-- Inject via the ExecutionContext in rangePartitioner -->
        <property name="parameterValues">
          <map>
            <entry key="fromId" value="#{stepExecutionContext[fromId]}" />
            <entry key="toId" value="#{stepExecutionContext[toId]}" />
          </map>
        </property>
        <property name="pageSize" value="10" />
        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="john.deere.com.EmpRowMapper" />
        </property>
      </bean>

    </beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

You step slave is defined outside of the job tag. That does not look correct

....

```
  </step>
</job>
  <step id="slave" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <tasklet>
```

....

Comment: if i wrote inside job.am getting same problem

Comment: What about all the beans, are you putting all the beans inside the job tag or outside?

Comment: Could you give this a different id. That would help narrow down the issue to this like . Instead of <step id="Step"> could you do <step id="FirstStep">

Comment: The beans should be outside the job tag.  You also need to make sure your accounting for the scope="step" by following these guidelines.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#step-scope

Comment: Same problem - as in the same error message?
Error creating bean with name "Step" or "FirstStep"?
....
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Step': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean class specified on bean defini

Comment: Error creating bean with name FirstStep org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Step': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean class specified on bean defini –

Comment: sorry am not having reputations to chat

Comment: No worries about that. Configuration look ok overall. I can't spot a problem from the info that's given. Probably need to look at the place you are auto-wiring the bean!

Comment: am not getting the solution.

Comment: Sorry couldn't help you out. You config looks ok to me :). Can't figure out whats wrong. Good luck!